# Python 2: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, dictionary

I have an **"asin.txt"** document:

```
in,Huawei1,DE
out,Huawei2,UK
out,Huawei3,none
in,Huawei4,FR
in,Huawei5,none
in,Huawei6,none
out,Huawei7,IT
```

I'm opening this file and make an `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
reader = csv.reader(open('asin.txt','r'),delimiter=',')
reader1 = csv.reader(open('asin.txt','r'),delimiter=',')
d = OrderedDict((row[0], row[1].strip()) for row in reader)
d1 = OrderedDict((row[1], row[2].strip()) for row in reader1)
```

Then I want to create variables (a,b,c,d) so if we take the first line of the `asin.txt` it should be like:  `a = in`; `b = Huawei1`; `c = Huawei1`; `d = DE`. To do this I'm using a "for" loop:

```
from itertools import izip
for (a, b), (c, d) in izip(d.items(), d1.items()): # here
    try:
      .......
```

It worked before, but now, for some reason, it prints an error:

```
 d = OrderedDict((row[0], row[1].strip()) for row in reader)
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

How do I fix that?

Comment: Looks like some line in your file breaks, owns only 0 or 1 field.

Comment: Have you checked that every line in your file is in the format you expect?  It's easy for blank lines to creep in at the end if you edit the file for example.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a row in your textfile which does not have at least two fields delimited by ",". E.g.:

```
in,Huawei1
```

Try to find the solution along these lines:

```
d = OrderedDict((row[0], row[1].strip()) for row in reader if len(row) >= 2)
```

or

```
l = []
for row in reader:
  if len(row) >= 2:
    l.append(row[0], row[1].strip())
d = OrderedDict(l)
```